# Can I using multiple processes to read different subsets of numpy array (or pandas dataframe) safely?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, multiprocessing

I want to use multiple processes to get each 2 columns combination in numpy array (or pandas dataframe), such as array[:, 1:3], array[:, 2:4].

**I wonder is it safe to get array[:, 1:3] in one process and get array[:, 2:4] in another process?**

The example code is shown:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value, Lock, Array

g = np.load('input.npy')
c = Value('i', 0, lock=True)

def count_valid_pairs(i):
    pair = g[:, i]
    global c

    if pair.max() > 100:
        with c.get_lock():
           c.value += 1
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':

    t_start = time.time()

    cpus = 20
    p = Pool(processes=cpus)
    r=p.imap_unordered(count_valid_pairs, combinations(range(g.shape[1]), 2))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print("Total {} pairs has max value > 100".format(c.value)
```

Comment: Yes it should work without any problem, you have any problem with this solution?

Comment: I highly doubt that this will be faster than a good vectorized approach. But as long as you only read the array in parallel, there will be no trouble.

Comment: This looks like a case for `stride_tricks.as_strided`.